# Circuit analysis (transient state) of a circuit with inductors and capacitors

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, power-electronics, inductor, transient

I am trying to perform transient state circuit analysis for the following circuit and find the voltages across the inductors:

[image]

I was using the superposition principle. I started by turning voltage source 1 OFF

Igot this circuit:

[image]

I got the following equations:

[image]

Then I turned Vin1 ON and Vin2 OFF and got this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faDBlE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think I need to do mesh analysis but I'm not sure how. I am trying to find the voltages across all the inductors.
After that I think I need to add the voltages equation of each inductor to find its voltage in the full circuit when both Vin1 and Vin2 are ON.

Comment: Are the input voltages DC? You've drawn DC voltage sources, but those don't make sense for this problem.

Comment: @Hearth this a mode of operation for a DC-DC converter, if you check the other question on my profile it has more information. I am trying to perform steady-state analysis of the converter.

Comment: So this is a transient analysis? You should make note of that.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYp8MV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_8
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_4}&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_8
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for the output voltage:

$$\text{V}_3=\dots\tag4$$

Notice that \$(4)\$ is an enormous fraction and I am not able to put it here in Latex. I provided a picture down here:

[image]

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_1=\text{sL}_1\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\text{sL}_2\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_5=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag9$$
- The input voltage 1 is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}_1\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_{\text{i}_1}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_1}{\text{s}}\tag{10}$$
- The input voltage 1 is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}_2\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_{\text{i}_2}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_2}{\text{s}}\tag{11}$$

So, we get for \$\text{v}_3\left(\text{s}\right)\$:

[image]

Now, we take the inverse Laplace transform of the equation above.

Solving a example we set \$\text{L}_1=\text{L}_2=1\space\text{H}\$, \$\text{C}_1=\text{C}_2=1\space\text{F}\$, \$\text{R}_4=\text{R}_6=1\space\Omega\$ and \$\hat{\text{u}}_1=\hat{\text{u}}_2=1\space\text{V}\$, so we get:

[image]

---

Using Mathematica I found the solutions:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I4 == I1 + I3, I2 == I0 + I3, I0 == I5 + I6, I7 == I5 + I6, 
   0 == I4 + I7 + I8, 0 == I1 + I2 + I8, I1 == (V1 - V4)/R1, 
   I2 == (V2 - V3)/R2, I3 == (V3 - V4)/R3, I4 == V4/R4, I5 == V3/R5, 
   I6 == V3/R6}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, V3, V4}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> ((R5 + R6) (R2 R4 V1 + R3 R4 V2 + R1 (R3 + R4) V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I1 -> (R2 ((R3 + R4) R5 + (R3 + R4 + R5) R6) V1 + 
    R5 R6 ((R3 + R4) V1 - R4 V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I2 -> (-R4 R5 R6 V1 + (R1 (R3 + R4) R5 + R4 R5 R6 + 
       R1 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R4 (R5 + R6)) V2)/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I3 -> (-R4 (R5 R6 + R2 (R5 + R6)) V1 + (R1 + R4) R5 R6 V2)/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I4 -> (R2 (R5 R6 + R3 (R5 + R6)) V1 + R5 R6 (R3 V1 + R1 V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I5 -> (R6 (R2 R4 V1 + R3 R4 V2 + R1 (R3 + R4) V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I6 -> (R5 (R2 R4 V1 + R3 R4 V2 + R1 (R3 + R4) V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I7 -> ((R5 + R6) (R2 R4 V1 + R3 R4 V2 + R1 (R3 + R4) V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  I8 -> -((R3 R5 R6 V1 + R2 ((R3 + R4) R5 + (R3 + R4 + R5) R6) V1 + 
     R3 (R1 + R4) (R5 + R6) V2 + R1 (R4 R5 + (R4 + R5) R6) V2)/(
    R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
        R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6)), 
  V3 -> (R5 R6 (R2 R4 V1 + R3 R4 V2 + R1 (R3 + R4) V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6), 
  V4 -> (R2 R4 (R5 R6 + R3 (R5 + R6)) V1 + R4 R5 R6 (R3 V1 + R1 V2))/(
   R2 (R3 R4 + R1 (R3 + R4)) R5 + (R1 R2 (R3 + R4) + R3 R4 R5 + 
       R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 + R2 R4 (R3 + R5)) R6)}}
```